# Does it really matter to have Response.CacheControl in a asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, iis, caching

I have a asp.net webapplication with an external include file with these parameters:

```
 Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
        Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "")
        Response.Expires = -1
```

The purpose is not to cache the page, but are those needed really? They are maybe some leftover from a time long ago. Doesn't every request serve a new page by default? By the way - we are using IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the page is doing, but in most cases that shouldn't be necessary.